# Why Doesn't Mathematica Evaluate This Integral?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integral

I am using Mathematica (the online version, but not WolframAlpha) and I'm trying to estimate the integral

```
$\int_{-1}^1 e^{\frac{i}{1+x^2}}\dx\,.$
```

To do so, I've entered

```
NIntegrate[E^[I/[1 + x^2]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

but instead of returning a number it just returns the integral I wrote above. Meanwhile, WolframAlpha estimates this just fine, as in

- https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+e%5E%28i%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29%2C+x%3D-1..1

I tried entering

```
NIntegrate[E^[I/[1 + x^2]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

and was expecting a number.

Comment: [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please don't post TeX here, stackoverflow does support it.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you, I will post it on mathematica.stackexchange as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a misunderstanding of `[]` versus `()` in Mathematica.

Try

```
NIntegrate[E^(I/(1 + x^2)), {x, -1, 1}]
```

which instantly returns

```
1.3958009479756124 + 1.39620125365813*I
```

In Mathematica, as opposed to WolframAlpha and "ordinary math"

`[]` always, well almost always, surround function arguments.

`()` group "ordinary" operands in expressions.

It takes a little while to get used to Mathematica conventions.